# Javascript/Vue js/Firestore: innerHTML is null, but it worked in the first time

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am working on my own projects I made a query and it gets the total users and store it in the **p** tag.

```
<v-card class="mt-10 mb-5 users" max-width="344">
    <v-card-text>
         <p class="display-1 text--primary text-center">Users</p>
         <div class="display-1 text--primary text-center">
             <p id="users"></p>
          </div>
     </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

```
created() {
     // Get all user profile
     db.collection("Profile").get().then((res) => {
          document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = res.size
      })
}
```

But now I get the error I didn't change anything.

**The error**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Comment: if you're using direct DOM manipulation (i.e. like innerHTML) in vuejs, you're using vuejs wrong - though, I don't see how `document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = res.size` is ever executed more than once (*it worked the first time*), nor how that element can disappear

Comment: Can you move your db.collection logic to `mounted` method and try again =). Probably in `create` method, DOM isn't ready :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not manipulate DOM directly as it's normally done while using `vanilla JS` (plain javascript) or `jQuery` because when you are using `vue.js` it'snice to follow reactive pattern.

```
<template>
  <p> {{ users }} </p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: 0
    };
  },

  // you can use created or mounted, see which works
  created() {
    db.collection("Profile").get().then((res) => {
      this.users = res.size
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You sure you meant `lang="pug"`?

Comment: @Phil thanks for letting me know, just updated - that's what happen when you copy+paste ;)

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, Vue works best when you use data to drive your templates. Directly manipulating the DOM is an anti-pattern.

For example, use a data property for the information you want to display and assign it a value when your query completes

```html
<p>{{ profileCount }}</p>
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ profileCount: null }),
  async created () {
    const { size } = await db.collection("Profile").get()
    this.profileCount = size
  }
}
```